# How can I copy a Window to a DynamicProject WorkSpace?

Tags: xmonad

I know how I can copy a window to a workspace with

```
    -- mod-control-shift-[1..9] @@ Copy client to workspace N
```

, but how is this done with DynamicProjects?;)